# ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = bytea,No operator matches the given name and argument types

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a JPA UNION query and In GET API swagger three field is there  institution(mandatory) ,txBookingLocation(mandatory) customerID(optional) working fine .If i remove 'AND (COALESCE(:customerID.....)' .both the select statement .without removing how it will work ?

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = bytea,No operator matches the given name and argument types
```

@Query(nativeQuery = true,value= "SELECT                                                                                                          "

```
                       + " customerid AS customerID,                                                                                          "
                       + " stepid AS stepID,                                                                                                  "
                  .....................
                       + "institution AS institution,                                                                                         "
                       + "limit_groupid AS limitGroupID,                                                                                      "
                       + "checkerid AS checkerID,                                                                                             "
                       + "checker_timestamp AS checkerTimestamp,                                                                              "
                       + "step_action AS stepAction,                                                                                          "
                       + "step_status AS stepStatus,                                                                                          "
                       + "tx_booking_location AS txBookingLocation,                                                                           "
                                      ...............                       
                      + "customer_name AS customerName                                                                                        "
                      +  "FROM  txrh_bcaterms where step_status IN ('SAV', 'REJ') " + " AND institution = :institution                        "
                      + " AND (COALESCE(:txBookingLocation, null) is null or (tx_booking_location IN :txBookingLocation))                     "
                      + " AND (COALESCE(:customerID, null) is null or (customerid = :customerID))    "
                     
                                                                                                                            
            + "UNION                                                                                                                           "

            + "SELECT                                                                                                                          "
                       + "customerid AS customerID,                                                                                            "
                       + "null AS stepID,                                                                                                      "
                      ...........
                       + "finance_type AS financeType,                                                                                         "
                   ....................
                       + "institution AS institution,                                                                                          "
                       + "limit_groupid AS limitGroupID,                                                                                       "
                       + "null AS checkerID,                                                                                                   "
                       + "null AS checkerTimestamp,                                                                                            "
                       + "null AS stepAction,                                                                                                  "
                       + " 'RLS' AS stepStatus,                                                                                                "
                       + "tx_booking_location AS txBookingLocation,                                                                            "
                              ............................
                      
                       + "customer_name AS customerName                                                                                        "
                       + "FROM  txrm_bcaterms where (institution, tx_booking_location,customerid) NOT IN                                                  "  
                       + " (select institution, tx_booking_location,customerid from txrh_bcaterms  where step_status IN ('SAV', 'REJ', 'PNR') "
                       + " AND (COALESCE(:txBookingLocation, null) is null or ( tx_booking_location IN :txBookingLocation))"
                       + " AND (COALESCE(:customerID, null) is null or (customerid = :customerID))    "
                       + " AND institution = :institution ) "
                       + " AND institution = :institution "
                       + " AND (COALESCE(:txBookingLocation, null) is null OR tx_booking_location IN :txBookingLocation)" 
                       + " AND (COALESCE(:customerID, null) is null or customerid = :customerID)" ,
                        
                    countQuery = " SELECT count(*) FROM ("
                            ....................
                            + ")as cnt")                       
Page<ITXBCATermsHistoryBookingLocationAndInstitutionDTO> historyAndMaster(
        @Param("institution") String institution,
        @Param("txBookingLocation")  List<String> txBookingLocation,
        @Param("customerID") String customerID,
        Pageable page);
```

}

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = bytea
```

I am not getting what has went wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the type of `customerid` column in your `txrh_bcaterms` table?

Comment: customerid varchar in both  txrh_bcaterms  and txrm_bcaterms table

Comment: could you please look to the issue where is the problem unable to find the root cause.